# c# webcontrol - how to load a html on the fly?

Tags: c#, browser

I would like to load HTML using c#'s webbrowser component. I looked up MSDN, but I can't find anything that can load a string(HTML) into webbrowser component. I only see navigate() method to load a URL.

so..I would like to the following if possible

```
String htmlcontent = "<html><head><title>test</title></head><body>my content here</body></html>";

webBrowser1.load(htmlContent)
```

something like this..I load that there is no `load()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [`DocumentText` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx).
Note that it's asynchronous; the content will not necessarily loaded when your next line of code runs.

Comment: can you please tell what should be use to show data when form loaded?

Comment: @Volatil3: The `WebBrowser` control has an event for that.