# Open Html code in browser

Tags: c#, html, .net, system.net.httpwebrequest

i have a **c# application**, which calls an **API and the response is in HTML format**.
i **don't want to save the HTML** code to a file but i want to open that **html code  in a browser**

i am able to display if the HTML is saved in a file using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToHtmlFile);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display the string html contents into webbrowser control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362591/how-to-display-the-string-html-contents-into-webbrowser-control)

Comment: not a duplicate question, i am using a console application and i don't want to save the html code in a file

Comment: That is fine. Whether you use it in Windows Application or console application, what you're trying to achieve looks same. That's why I marked it as a duplicate.

Comment: there is no accepted answer in that and the answers are not solving my issue

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show your html code in an external browser then you *have to* temporary save your code to a file and execute by the browser with Process.Start.

You can display the html code in your own Application with the WebBrowser-Control.
Don't forget to use the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx)
 Event to ensure that `WebBrowser.Document` is not null.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `WebBrowser` Control from your Windows Application:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();

// Navigate to URL
browser.Navigate("http://www.somesite.com");

// Set HTML code
browser.Document.Write("<html><body>...</body></html>");

// Another way to set HTML code
browser.DocumentText = "<html><body>...</body></html>";
```

> Please use this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution

Comment: browser.Document it returns always null

Comment: You may use browser.DocumentText in that case :)

Comment: i used that but nothing happens, no browser is opened with my html code