# Awesomium WebControl load string

Tags: c#, wpf, awesomium

Is there a way to load a html as a string in webControl?

Something like:

```
webControl.Load("<!DOCTYPE html><html>...");
```

Like used in the normal wpf webControl:

```
webControl.NavigateToString("<!DOCTYPE html><html>...");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4467219/1214743 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/5362591/1214743 , Have you googled this?

Comment: But this only works with the normal webcontrol that comes with Visual Studio. Awesomium webControl doesn't have this property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually now I found the answer in the tutorials for C++ (not on .net wpf) in Awesomium site.

Here is my solution:

```
 var uri = new Uri("data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><html>...", UriKind.Absolute);

            webControl.Source = uri;
```

Comment: This fails if html string is too large. I'm getting an error: `Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.`

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question but here is how I menaged to do it :

```
var page = new WebControl
{
    ViewType = WebViewType.Window,
};  
page.NativeViewInitialized += (s, e) =>
{
    page.LoadHTML("<html>SOME TEXT</html>");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a URL in the source just put your HTML in there

[image: Awsomium]

loaded from [Awesomium tutorials](http://wiki.awesomium.net/wpf/webcontrol.html#creating_a_webcontrol)

Comment: i appreciate the effort to help me, but this is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:
 Load html string to a file and then load page using webControl.Source property.

```
 public static string WriteHtmlToTempFile(string html)
 {
     var fileName = GetTempFileName("html");
     System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, html);
     return fileName;

 }
 var strHtml = "<HTML> Hello World</HTML>";
 var file = Common.WriteHtmlToTempFile(strHtml);
 var wUri = new Uri(string.Format(@"file://{0}", file   ));
 webControl2.Source = wUri;
```