# How load html text, rather than html file in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am currently creating a winforms project and we have returned an html string from some method and now want to load it into the WebBrowser.

I know I can use the

`WebBrowser.Document.Write()`

to write html text to Webbrowser.

But my production environment doesn't allow me to do that.

The alternative is to try to navigate it to a temporary html file using

`WebBrowser.Navigate(@"temp file location")`

What I'm asking is:

For security reasons, redundant temporary files are not allowed in production environment.

Is there any way to skip the step of creating a temporary file?

Trying to find a way to implement it using `Navigate`.

Comment: You can set the DocumentText property of the WebBrowser control to a string. Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467219/c-sharp-webcontrol-how-to-load-a-html-on-the-fly and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362591/how-to-display-the-string-html-contents-into-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 0):

How have they restricted `webBrowser.Document.Write()` in production?

Can you access `webBrowser.DocumentText = html;`?

Also you could try:

```
string html = "Your HTML Here";
string dataUrl = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + Uri.EscapeDataString(html);
webBrowser.Navigate(dataUrl);
```